# OpenCV Read 3D Raw Image

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I have some raw images that are tridimensional rocks from CT Scan.
So, what I need is to read those images as an array of images, like vectors of cv::Mat. Does anyone have any clue or tips for how to do this?

Link for a sample:
https://imperialcollegelondon.app.box.com/s/q0e1ay5tfluyyzmy7lgjz2jdjbhe6tve

Comment: Try to contact your CT Scan vendor for c++ libraries

Comment: What are the dimensions of your images? Do you have a collection of raw 2D images or one raw 3D image?

Comment: This is for my Graduate Conclusion Work and this dataset is commonly used in the literature. The image dimension is 1000 Cubic, I believe that it is one raw 3D.

Comment: The full dataset can be found here:http://www.imperial.ac.uk/earth-science/research/research-groups/perm/research/pore-scale-modelling/micro-ct-images-and-networks/

Comment: Try this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59669598/8682939). Let me know if it works.